# Toggle Unordered List display mode depending on content width

Tags: css

**My question:**

Is there a way to automatically switch `UL>LI` display mode (*vertical/horizontal - `block/inline-block`*) depending on LI's content width  (*without JS/Jquery*)?

---

**Situation:**

- I have a list graphically set using CSS.
- This list is only displaying 3 items, in different languages (multi-language website).
- For english website, the container is large enought to display the list horizontally. Unfortunately, for the german website, items aren't displayed on 1 line. That's why I would like the whole list to be displayed vertically. I can do it using a special class for german website, but I would like a solution that work for both.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dw05q7jd/4/)

---

**Specifications**

- I would like to find a solution without JS/jQuery
- I would like to use the same class for english/german list

Is it possible ?

Thanks for reading/commenting/answering.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because in CSS there is no `if`'s. Why jQuery is not allowed for that?

Comment: It is not forbidden, just wanted to find a "clean css" way to do that.

Comment: Some of the German menu items may be less long than others.  It may complicate your design and not give the clean look you desire.  I will suggest to prepare a separate css document for German.

Comment: It should be a way to do, but I don't only have 2 languages (7 in real), and I already have special CSS files for responsive design. If I have to specify special class for some languages, depending on screen resolution, and taking in account that some browsers are not rendering fonts the same way (Firefox fo exemple), it is kind of russian roulet trying to find witch language have to use the specific class :(